# Por que a minha regEx não resulta o esperado?

Tags: javascript, regex

Eu realmente tenho dificuldade em montar expressões regulares, principalmente por variar seu comportamento em cada linguagem. Estou traduzindo um código Java para JS, no qual a expressão regular é `/(\d{1,4}|\*)\s*[xX]\s*(\d{1,4}|\*)/`, pelo o que entendi ela captura qualquer número (tamanho de 1 a 4 caracteres) que tenham ao menos o X ou x separando de outro conjunto de números. 
Minha dúvida é: Por que não consigo capturar "1024x768 px até 1920x1080" para que dê match **também** em "1920x1080"?
JS

```
function process(val) {
    if (val != null) {
        val = val.replace("X", "x");
        val = val.replace(/ /g, "");
        const DIMENSAO_UNIT = "px";
        const DIMENSAO_PATTERN = /(\d{1,4}|\*)\s*[xX]\s*(\d{1,4}|\*)/;
        var normalizado = val.trim().toLowerCase().replace(DIMENSAO_UNIT, "");
        var valores = [];
        var out = "";
        if (DIMENSAO_PATTERN.test(val)) {
            var getNumbers = val.match(DIMENSAO_PATTERN);
            var i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < getNumbers.length; i++) {
                valores.push(getNumbers[i]);
            }
        }
        if(val == ""){
            return "";
        }
        if (normalizado.indexOf("superior") > -1) {
            return valores[0] + DIMENSAO_UNIT + " ou superior";
        } else if (normalizado.indexOf("até") > -1) {
            if (valores.length == 1) {
                out = "até " + valores[0];
            } else {
                out = valores[0] + " até " + valores[1];
            }
        } else if (normalizado.indexOf("ou") > -1 || normalizado.indexOf("/") > -1) {
            out = valores[0];
            var j = 0;
            for (j = 1; j < valores.length; j++) {
                out = "/" + valores[j];
            }
        } else {
            if (valores.length > 0) {
                out = valores[0];
            }
        }
        if (out !== null || out !== "") {
            return out + DIMENSAO_UNIT;
        }
        return "";
    }
    return null;
}
```

[Teste regEx](https://regex101.com/r/zP8qB9/1<br)

****UPDATE:** Faltava apenas adicionar o global (g): `/(\d{1,4}|\*)\s*[xX]\s*(\d{1,4}|\*)/g` mas deixo aberto p explicações

Comment: Consegui, deu certo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema não está na *regex*, como você bem percebeu, mas nas funções do JavaScript de manipulação de *regexes*. A função [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) do tipo `String` retorna:

- O primeiro casamento encontrado, junto com seus grupos de captura, se a expressão regular não possui a *flag* `g`;
- Todos os casamentos encontrados, se a *regex* posui a *flag* `g`. Nesse caso, os grupos de captura são ignorados.

Exemplo:

```js
var str = "abracadabra";

var regex1 = /a(.)/;
var regex2 = /a(.)/g;

var match1 = str.match(regex1);
var match2 = str.match(regex2);

document.body.innerHTML += "<p>" + JSON.stringify(match1) + "</p>";
document.body.innerHTML += "<p>" + JSON.stringify(match2) + "</p>";
```

Comment: Apenas uma dúvida no código: compilando online permite que execute essa linha numa só: `val = val.replace("X", "x").replace(/ /g, "");` mas no intelliJ o segundo replace não é encontrado como uma função, tenho que colocar como: `val = val.replace("X", "x");val = val.replace(/ /g, "");`. É "frescura" da IDE ou isso não é permitido mesmo?

Comment: JavaScript possui tipagem dinâmica, o que torna difícil analisar um código estaticamente e determinar o que uma variável contém, qual o seu tipo, que métodos se aplicam a ela. Nós sabemos que o método `replace` retorna uma string - e portanto pode-se chamar métodos de string no retorno - mas o analisador de código da IDE não vai necessariamente saber disso.